# Local Database using linq to sql

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I`m using VS2012 SDK for WP8.
I need to know if it is possible to create a local database for mobile, as separated c# class, and not under the MainPage class.
if yes, is there anything special that should be added to make it work ?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a local relational database in the form of an `.SDF` file, that is stored in your app's local folder. This can then be accessed through `LINQ-to-SQL`.

I suggest you read into this, [Local database for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202860%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Comment: Could you explain *why* that solution isn't suitable for you?

Comment: Then your question is kind of ambiguous. Consider being more specific!

Comment: I have read this article, thanks. but I am looking for something else. I want to remove the table creating and handling code from the MainPage class, and I want to put it in a new class called MyDataBase class, and to call this class methods from the MainPage class or any other class

Comment: If you really want that, you can create a singleton that stores all of your data. There are several questions about this already, such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276292/c-sharp-separate-class-for-storage

Comment: You are talking about a C# class as if it was a database. If you want a C# class to store information in an object, it is not a database. A local database is exactly what my answer supplied you with. A singleton will be a class that can be instantiated only once, and used for whatever you want, such as store information.

Comment: If you look into the link you gave, they are telling us to write the local database as part of the MainPage class. I would like to move this large code, since I have a much bigger database, to external file that I can include to another class and use its method to add, remove, modify and query the database. my apologies if I didn`t explain myself correctly.

Comment: Then do not put the database code in the main class but instead a separate class? You can still use a local .SDF database. The example is just... an example.